# use named Assetic resource in BlockService

Tags: symfony, assetic, symfony-sonata

Which service do I inject into my custom block service so that I can use assetic to generate a valid absolute url for block-specific resources (both js and css)? I want something like this:

```php
class CustomBlockService extends Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService {

    protected $urlmaker;

    function __construct($name, $templating, SomeService $urlmaker){
        parent::__construct($name, $templating);
        $this->urlmaker = $urlmaker;
    }

    public function getStylesheets($media)
    {
        return array(
            $this->urlmaker('treegrid_css');
        );
    }

    public function getJavascripts($media)
    {
        return array(
            $this->urlmaker('treegrid_js');
        );
    }

    //rest of class
}
```

## Background

I'm using [SonataBlockBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/index.html) to output some custom blocks. Some of the blocks require javascripts (or css) that aren't used anywhere else. So in my base template, I did this:

```
    {% block javascripts %}
        <!-- scripts on every page -->
        {% javascripts
              '@jquery_js'
              '@bootstrap_js'
              '@select2_js'
              '@sonata_base_js'
        %}
              <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}

        <!-- BLOCK-SPECIFIC scripts -->
        {{ sonata_block_include_javascripts('all') }}
    {% endblock %}
```

The sonata twig extension `sonata_block_include_javascripts` requires the custom block service to override this function if it wants to specify javascripts:

```php
public function getJavascripts($media)
{
    return array(
        'bundles/bundlename/path/to/script.js'
    );
}
```

My Symfony project is set up so that Bower-managed components live here:

`%kernel.root.dir%/Resources/components/bower_components`, a path that SonataBlockBundle unfortunately outputs relative to `web`.

I have a config file for Assetic, assetic.yml, which names each resource that I might want to include. By doing this I don't have to fight with Assetic about file paths when I switch from dev to prod environments. I also don't have to rely on resources bundled with thirdparty packages unless I wish to. (e.g. umpty different versions of jQuery, one for each package!)

assetic.yml excerpt

```
assets:
    jquery_js:
      inputs:
        - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/components/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js'
    jqueryui_js:
      inputs:
        - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/components/bower_components/jqueryui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js'
        - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/components/bower_components/jqueryui/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js'
    bootstrap_js:
      inputs:
        - %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/components/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
    treegrid_js:
      inputs:
        - %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/components/bower_components/treegrid/js/jquery.treegrid.js
        - %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/components/bower_components/treegrid/js/jquery.treegrid.bootstrap3.js
    main_css:
      inputs: 
        - %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/components/css/main.css
      filters: [cssrewrite]
    treegrid_css:
      inputs:
        -%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/components/bower_components/treegrid/css/jquery.treegrid.css
```